# What is the right way to merge branches when `git diff` shows changes but `git merge` does nothing

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

I get stumped when `git diff other_branch` shows differences and `git merge other_branch` does nothing. What's the right way to incorporate that "missing" code into `my_branch`?

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408064/623735) diagramed a situation similar to mine.

```
o---A---B---C-------G   my_branch
     \       \     /
      --*D*---E---F    other_branch
```

Surprisingly changes in *D* aren't automatically merged into `my_branch` when I do

```
git checkout my_branch
git merge other_branch
```

to bring in *F* to *G*

Of course I can [manually create a patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418499/623735) and apply it to `my_branch`, like this:

```
git diff other_branch my_branch > patchfile
git checkout my_branch
patch -p1 < patchfile
```

But I want to do this right, without mucking up the git log. With the patch approach, git will record the changes in *D* and my latest patch as happening independently of each other (code churn). I want to simplify the `git log` and make sure others don't have unintended things happen (quietly and insidiously) when they do a `git merge my_branch`.

Comment: Did you try to merge `my_branch` into `other_branch`? Probably that could resolve the differences. If some commits got reverted in `my_branch` but not in `other_branch` you will end up in a situation like this.

Comment: @iltempo, I tried the merge after your comment, and yea it did indeed resolve the differences and the git diff is now clean. I just have to trust that it merged appropriately.

Comment: @iltempo, I didn't intentionally revert any changes in `my_branch`, but may very well have--by hitting save in sublime (text editor) after oscillating between checkouts and edits and checkouts interspersed with commits. I need to be more careful about all that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem to have two issues here at the same time.

Assuming a history like the one you described:

```
                my_branch
                    v
----A---B---C-------G   
     \       \     /
      --*D*---E---F
                  ^
             other_branch
```

---

**Why the diff is not empty:**

This situation is produced by the commands you mentioned, i.e. **being on `my_branch` and then doing `git merge other_branch`**. This action produced a merge commit `G` and moved the current branch (`my_branch`) forward, but left `other_branch` where it was. This is how merges always work! Naturally, there will still be a difference between `my_branch` (`G`) and `other_branch` (`F`) at this point -- they point to different commits after all.

If you want the two branches to be identical, you can move up `other_branch` in the following ways:

1. `git checkout other_branch; git merge my_branch` -- this is a *fast-forward* merge since `G` is a descendant of `F`
2. *[while not on `other_branch`!]* `git branch -D other_branch; git branch other_branch my_branch` -- this will remove `other_branch` and then re-create it in the same location where `my_branch` currently is
3. `git checkout other_branch; git reset --hard my_branch` -- this will *move* `other_branch` to point exactly where `my_branch` is currently pointing

After doing **one** of these steps, both `my_branch` and `other_branch` will be pointing to `G`.

---

**Why the changes of commit `D` are not in `my_branch` (`G`)**

Git merges histories, not changes. This usually means that Git will take the two sides of a merge (and, if available, their youngest common ancestor commit, aka the [*merge-base*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)) and try to combine them. Since Git commits are **snapshots**, not changesets/deltas/diffs, this no information of other commits or changes is used in the actual merge.

Using the merge-base, Git does a so-called three-way merge, using the common ancestor to try and smartly resolve the changes on both sides. If it can't it will interrupt the merge and require the user to resolve the conflicts.

**What probably happened** in your history is that either commit `E` or `F` reverted (or overrode) the changes of `D` -- this might have happened during the merge which produced `E` or actual (manual) changes in `F`.

As you yourself mentioned in a comment, you often switch between commits and make edits. You will thereby be floating changes a lot (Git carries uncommitted changes over during checkouts), which might very well make it difficult to tell where changes should go and where they actually do go. Try to avoid this by either committing any changes before changing branches or using [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) to buffer them.